# error with curl google map

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

```
 function getGeoCoords($address)
 {
  $coords = array();



  $address = utf8_encode($address);


  $geoCodeURL = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".
               urlencode($address)."&sensor=false&key=ApiKey(AIzaSyDaepez9PYv_74hAv34spbNfeWOo26OhgM)";



  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $geoCodeURL);

   $result = curl_exec ($curl);

 var_dump($result); 


 }
```

Hello friends when i run the above query it  executes "bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)",i have tried everything,but nothing is helpful,pls help me guys,

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a glance, the first thing I see is the `ApiKey`, try to put it directly as

```
key=AIzaSyDaepez9PYv_74hAv34spbNfeWOo26OhgM
```

the $geoCodeURL variable should be assigned like this:

```
$geoCodeURL = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" .
             urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDaepez9PYv_74hAv34spbNfeWOo26OhgM";
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply,can you please suggest me where shall i put the Api key

Comment: I've edited the answer showing how should be assigned the api key to the geoCodeUrl variable.

Comment: Hi @khan, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.